# How to delete recursively rendered components in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am quite new to React and TypeScript. I have a scenario where multiple-sub components need to be able to delete "themselves".

- Component A renders components B & C
- Component B renders components B1 & B2
- Component C renders components C1 & C2

Parent Component A contains an object that holds the data for each component:

Interfaces to demonstrate the data component A holds:

```
interface Parent { id: number; name: string; children: Child1[]} (Component A. children is Component A & B)
interface Child1 { id: number; name: string; children: Child2[]} (Component B & C. Children is B1, B2, C1 & C2)
interface Child2 { id: number; name: string;} (Component B1,B2,C1 & C2)
```

Basic component markup:

```
const ComponentA = () => {
  const data: Parent = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'stackoverflow',
    children: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'child1',
        children: [
          {
            id: 4,
            name: 'child2',
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            name: 'child2',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'child1',
        children: [
          {
            id: 6,
            name: 'child2',
          },
          {
            id: 7,
            name: 'child2',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  };

  return (
    <div id={data.id}>
      <span>{data.name}</span>
      <button>Delete button to delete this component </button>
      <div>
        {data.children.map((child1: Child1) => {
          <Child1 data={child1} />
        }}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};

const Child2 = (data: Child2) => {
  <div id={data.id}>
    <span>{data.name}</span>
    <button>Delete button to remove this component</button>
  </div>
};

const Child1 = (data: Child1) => {
  return (
    <div id={data.id}>
      <span>{data.name}</span>
      <button>Delete button to remove this component</button>
      <div>
        {data.children.map((child2: Child2) => {
          return (<Child2 key={child2.id} data={child2} />);
        }}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};
```

If I click on a delete button located in component C2 I want to be able to remove this data from component C which I guess I also have to remove on component A.

My question is on how I should proceed to delete something like this?

Do I pass a method from Component A to B & C and from B & C to B1, B2 & C1 to C2?
Do I also have to pass the whole "parent" object then downwards or perhaps only the id as a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function that recursively searches the element with matching id and deletes it.

One interface is sufficient for giving type to the data. Here's an example:

```
const Component: FC<Props> = ({ data, deleteHandler }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {data.map(({ id, children, name }) => (
        <div key={id}>
          <span>{name}</span>
          <button onClick={() => deleteHandler(id)}>delete</button>
          {Array.isArray(children) && (
            <Component data={children} deleteHandler={deleteHandler} />
          )}
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

const recursiveDelete = (data: Parent[], deleteId: number): Parent[] => {
  const updatedData = data.reduce((acc, el) => {
    if (el.id !== deleteId) {
      const updatedEl = { ...el };
      if (Array.isArray(updatedEl.children)) {
        updatedEl.children = recursiveDelete(updatedEl.children, deleteId);
      }
      acc.push(updatedEl);
    }
    return acc;
  }, [] as Parent[]);
  return updatedData;
};

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Parent[]>(initialData);

  const deleteHandler = (id: number) => {
    setData((prevData) => recursiveDelete(prevData, id));
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Component data={data} deleteHandler={deleteHandler} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit magical-shaw-fewwj]